# TypeScript, declare a variable vs. declare a module

Tags: typescript, typescript1.6

**TL;DR**

What does it mean when a variable is declared in typescript? For example (from the TypeScript handbook or wiki):

declare var d3: D3.Base;

What is the purpose in this case?

**More thoughts:**

I understand that declaring a module or namespace indicates that it is ambient, i.e. it is not compiled into JavaScript and is only used for describing the shape of objects (type checking). However, the purpose of variable declaration eludes me.

The question arose as I was looking at the angular declaration file from definitely typed (angular.d.ts):

```
declare var angular: angular.IAngularStatic;

// Support for painless dependency injection
interface Function {
    $inject?: string[];
}

// Collapse angular into ng
import ng = angular;
// Support AMD require
declare module 'angular' {
    export = angular;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// ng module (angular.js)
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
declare module angular {......module declaration continues....
```

I'm struggling to figure out exactly what's going on here with the "import" and variable declaration. Visual Studio Code doesn't seem to like the import, but Visual Studio 2015 accepts it (both use TypeScript 1.6.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the purpose in this case

Ambient Declarations. Primarily to support libraries (and environment variables like `window`) that are not written in TypeScript.

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/intro.html

> However, the purpose of variable declaration eludes me.

Some libraries provide a *global* variable. E.g. `$` by jquery.

This topic is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/variables.html

> I'm struggling to figure out exactly what's going on here with the "import" and variable declaration

`import` can be used to copy the *type* (here `declare module angular`).

This is covered in the `tips` section here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html

Comment: Thanks for the link to your book. I'll definitely take a look. It's funny, I was reading through the language specification and found the jquery and Window example there: [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1.1)  Is "import" supposed to be used in that manner? Why do you think Visual Studio Code isn't supporting its usage? Bug?

Comment: `Why do you think Visual Studio Code isn't supporting its usage? Bug?` I try not to spend spare time on non OSS projects... so who knows :)

Comment: Is that usage of "import" part of the TypeScript language spec? I'm trying to determine if I should use that syntax as well.

Comment: `Is that usage of "import" part of the TypeScript language spec?` Useful to collapse stuff like `foo.bar.bas` into `bas` e.g. `import bas = foo.bar.bas`

Comment: Visual Studio Code is now OSS, yay!